# Lookup enum value in a map to initialise list

Tags: java, enums, java-8, maps

Given I have the following `Map` and call to `writeMetadata(...)`:

```
Map<Report, TransferStatus> transferStatusMap = sftpService.transfer(reportDeliverables);

dbMetadataWriter.writeMetadata(successReports);
```

`ENUM` as:

```
public enum TransferStatus {
    SUCCESS,
    FAILURE
}
```

Firstly, how can I create the `successReport` list with all `Report` with status `TransferStatus.SUCCESS` with Java 8?

Secondly, before call to `dbMetadataWriter.writeMetadata(successReports);` there should be a check to see if any values with success exist.

and finally, in general how should failed transfers be handled? Practically, what is best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 List<Report> successReports = transferStatusMap.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .filter(e -> e.getValue() == TransferStatus.SUCCESS)
          .map(Entry::getKey)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

 if(!reports.isEmpty()){
     dbMetadataWriter.writeMetadata(successReports);
 }
```

Or you could collect them both to a `Map`:

```
Map<TransferStatus, List<Report>> map = 
     transferStatusMap.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Entry::getValue,
                            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: I liked the second example you had earlier. Will it create multiple keys of `Success`? or there will be only 2 keys say success and failure which I can work with.

Comment: @user2781389 *multiple same* keys in a `Map`?

Comment: keys will be unique in this case if i were to add `Report` to same same ENUM key? any thoughts on the final part of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the list of successReports as:

```
Map<Report, TransferStatus> transferStatusMap = sftpService.transfer(reportDeliverables);

List<Report> successReports = transferStatusMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(TransferStatus.SUCCESS))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Similarily writeMetaData if any such entry in the map exists

```
Map<Report, TransferStatus> transferStatusMap = sftpService.transfer(reportDeliverables);

if(transferStatusMap.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(x->x.getValue().equals(TransferStatus.SUCCESS))) {
        dbMetadataWriter.writeMetadata(successReports);
}
```

***Note***: If these are consecutive or sequential statements, [@Eugene's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46542824/1746118) is better in doing isEmpty() check over the existing datatype.

Comment: let's call it even, wanted to down-vote ;) ... why would you call `anyMatch` when a simple `successReports.size() > 0 ` would do?

Comment: @Eugene well agreed just solved in a decoupled way and while looking at your answer realized, its not really required.